How can I get correct dashed line of this Intersection?
This is my code
Clear["Global`*"]
myh = 5;
myr = 4;
pA = {0, 0, myh};
pO = {0, 0, 0};
cone1 = Cone[{pO, pA}, myr];
plane = InfinitePlane[{{0, 3, 0}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 2}}];
plotcone1 = 
  RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[cone1, plane], 
   BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
basegraph = 
  Show[plotcone1, 
   Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.8], cone1, plane}, Boxed -> False]];
ResourceFunction["Graphics3DSketch"][basegraph]

I get

Can I get like this?


The main part of the cone is in front of the plane.
